# Spring boot WebFlux is not working with Azure function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I am new in Azure functions and I am trying to use it through apring boot application. I am trying to return Mono of Application from create function. Instead of returning application JSON it is giving following JSON object.

```
{
  "onErrorCall": {},
  "optimizableOperator": {},
  "source": {}
}
```

create Function Bean

```
@Bean
    public Function<Message<Application>, Mono<Application>> create() {
        return message -> Mono.just(message.getPayload());
    }
```

create Function handler

```
@FunctionName("create")
  public HttpResponseMessage execute(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.POST},
    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Application> request,
                                     ExecutionContext context) {
    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
      .body(handleRequest(request.getBody(), context))
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .build();
  }
```

pom.xml have following dependencies

1. spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure
2. spring-boot-starter-webflux

Spring boot version 2.4.6-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Same problem here when extending "FunctionInvoker". If instead extending "AzureSpringBootRequestHandler" it is working. Problem is that "AzureSpringBootRequestHandler" is marked deprecated in favor of  "FunctionInvoker".